# how can I modify the value of a transform when playing back a bag file?

Tags: ros, geometry, transform, time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just like there are message filters, would it be possible to make tf filters?

I often find I want to modify the value of a single node in the tf tree when I have a bagfile, or to eliminate broadcasts on tf altogether.

It also could be useful to associate/utilize multiple tf's together, even when broadcast at different rates. Like [ApproximateTime](http://www.ros.org/wiki/message_filters/ApproximateTime) can do with messages

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10157/how-can-i-modify-the-value-of-a-transform-when-playing-back-a-bag-file?/) by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 682 on 2011-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a tool called [tf_remap](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf#tf_remap) which does approximately what you want.  You can use the mappings to rename the unwanted frames and then republish them using another process.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure how the subject relates to the text, but I think you are not looking for a [tf::MessageFilter](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Using%20Stamped%20datatypes%20with%20tf%3A%3AMessageFilter), or are you?

For eliminating /tf you might be able to remap the /tf topic to some other topic.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-06-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-06-05**:
My guess is you can't remap certain parts of the tf tree to something else, but someone might have a solution. Matching transforms based on the stamps should be done by the tf library automatically.

**Comment by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) on 2011-06-04**:
Thanks for the link. Not exactly what I was thinking of, but its certainly a useful feature. Instead of remapping all of /tf, I wonder if I could remap only one transform on the /tf tree. Mostly, I want to match transforms based on their broadcast stamps